# editable dynamic php table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am creating a table dynamically that is editable. It works great, perhaps too good for what i need. With my table i have a edit column with a change button for each row and is automatically created at the end of the table. And you have to click a change button on the row to edit it. I would like to get rid of the edit buttons/column(that way the user can click on the cell button and it will always be editable) and make it to where the user can only edit the row that is assigned to them with their specific id. Also i cannot figure out how to create a box that pops up when the cell button is clicked, the user will have options within the popup box that when the user chooses the option it loads the data to the cell.
 Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 $tbvbr= $_SESSION['gamecode'];
 $pn = $_POST['playername'];

 function stripslashes2( $string ) 
{ 
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
    return stripslashes( $string ); 
} else { 
    return $string; 
}  
}  

function display_db_query( $tablename, $header_bool , $border ) 
{  
// find out the number of columns in result 
$result = mysql_query( "SHOW FIELDS FROM $tablename" ); 
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) { 
    if ( $row['Key'] == "PRI" ) 
        $primarykey = $row['Field']; 
    else 
        $field[$row['Field']] = array( $row['Type'] ); 
}  

if ( isset( $_POST["update$tablename"] ) ) { 
    $sql = sprintf( "update $tablename SET " ); 
    $sqlfields = array(); 

    foreach( $field AS $k => $v ) { 
        if ( !empty( $_POST["edit"][$k] ) ) 
            $sqlfields[] = "$k='" . mysql_real_escape_string( stripslashes2(             $_POST["edit"][$k] ) ) . "'"; 
        else 
            $sqlfields[] = "$k = NULL "; 
    }  
    if ( count( $sqlfields ) > 0 ) { 
        $sql .= implode( " , " , $sqlfields ) . " WHERE $primarykey=" . intval(  $_POST["updateid"] ) ; 

    mysql_query( $sql ) OR DIE( mysql_error() ); 
    if ( mysql_affected_rows() > 0 ) 
        print "Updated succesfully<br />"; 
    }  
    else 
    echo "No change<br />"; 
}  
// perform the database query 
$result_id = mysql_query( "SELECT * from $tablename" ) 
or die( "display_db_query:" . mysql_error() ); 

if ( $header_bool ) { 
    echo "<table width='850' $border align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1'    class='entryTable'>"; 
    echo "<tr class='entryTableHeader'>"; 
    foreach( $field AS $k => $v ) 
    print( "<td><center><b>$k</b></center></td>" ); 

    print( "<td><center><b>Edit</b></center></td> 
    </tr>\n" ); 
    } else 
    echo "<table width='850' $border align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='1'   class='entryTable'> "; 

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_id ) ) { 
    print( "<tr>" ); 
    if ( isset( $_GET["editmode"] ) AND $_GET["editmode"] == $row[$primarykey] ) { 
        $editmodeison = true; 
        echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"{$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]}\">"; 
    } else 
        $editmodeison = false; 

    foreach( $field AS $k => $v ) { 
        if ( $editmodeison ) 
            print( "<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"button\"  name=\"edit[$k]\" value=\"" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( '' ) ) . "\" /></td>\n" ); 
        else 
            print( "<td class='content' align='center'>" . ( !empty( $row[$k] )?htmlspecialchars( $row[$k] ) : htmlspecialchars( 'change' ) ) . "</td>\n" ); 
    }  

    if ( $editmodeison ) 
        print( "<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"updateid\" value=\"{$row[$primarykey]}\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"update$tablename\" value=\"update\"></form></td>\n" ); 
    else 

        print( "<td class='content' align='center'><a href=\"{$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]}?   editmode=" . $row[$primarykey] . "\">change</a></td>\n" ); 

    print( "</tr>\n" ); 
}  
print( "</table>\n" ); 
}  

 ?> 
 <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Products Orderable table</TITLE></HEAD> 
 <BODY> 
 <TABLE><TR><TD> 
 <?php 

 /* DB info  */ 
$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "placeholder"; 
$dbpass = "placeholder"; 
$dbname = "placeholder"; 
mysql_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass ) or die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL server" ); 
mysql_select_db( "$dbname" ); 
mysql_query( "SET NAMES utf8" ); 

$table = $tbvbr; 

display_db_query( $table, // $global_dbh, 
true, "border='2'" ); 

 ?> 
</TD></TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: You know `mysql_*` is deprecated right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Content Editable too. Here is a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliasm2k/TbLyb/) illustrating it.

```
dom.contentEditable = true;
```

Set that and any DOM object can be edited. You may probably use the `click` event to enable or disable content editable property.

Answer (score 0):

to answer my own question i edited out

```
    if ( $editmodeison ) 
        print( "<td class='content' align='center'><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"updateid\" value=\"{$row[$primarykey]}\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"update$tablename\" value=\"update\"></form></td>\n" ); 
     else 

        print( "<td class='content' align='center'><a href=\"{$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]}?editmode=" . $row[$primarykey] . "\">change</a></td>\n" );
```

and i set

```
 $_GET["editmode"]
```

to the variable id that was assigned to the user.

I also used the following Javascript

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
 function reply_click(clicked_name)
 {
var clicked_name;
document.location="http://www.localhost.com/update.php?location=" + clicked_name;

  }
  </script>
```